ANSIBLE resolve variable in when with jinja templating
I try to resolve Variable item within failed_when and changed_when statement. Because of this ANSIBLE-Doku I can't surround item with {{ }}

Conditionals are always run through Jinja2 as to resolve the expression, so when:, failed_when: and changed_when: are always templated and you should avoid adding {{ }}.

Any idea how to resolve item variable here?
  - name: "Do somesting"
    command: |
      some_command_code
    register: result
    failed_when: "'* DONE (item)' not in result.stderr"
    changed_when: "'* DONE (item)' in result.stderr"
    with_items: "{{packages}}"

When I try to surround the variable item with {{ }}
  - name: "Do somesting"
    command: |
      some_command_code
    register: result
    failed_when: "'* DONE ({{item}})' not in result.stderr"
    changed_when: "'* DONE ({{item}})' in result.stderr"
    with_items: "{{packages}}"

I get the following error message.
changed_when_result: 'The conditional check ''''* DONE ({{item}})'' in r_result.stderr'' failed. The error was: Conditional is marked as unsafe, and cannot be evaluated.'


All the when and *_when are Jinja templated already, you should have a warning from Ansible about that already. So: failed_when: "'* DONE (' ~ item ')' not in result.stderr"; changed_when: "'* DONE (' ~ item ')' in result.stderr"

https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#other-operators

Thanks of the explanation of ~ following code solves the problem.
changed_when: "'* DONE (' ~ item ~ ')' in r_result.stderr"
